# IllegalArgumentException: Authorities list must not be null

Tags: java, spring

I'm writing a web app in Java Spring. I have this piece of code which causes some trouble:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
user.setAuthorities(authorities);

UserDetails userDetails = new MyUserDetails(user);
jdbcUserDetailsManager.setDataSource(jdbc.getDataSource());
jdbcUserDetailsManager.setJdbcTemplate(jdbc);
jdbcUserDetailsManager.createUser(userDetails);
```

The last line causes an exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authorities list must not be null

This is the MyUserDetails class:

```
public final class MyUserDetails extends MyUser implements UserDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MyUserDetails (MyUser user) {
    super(user);
    this.setPassword(user.getPassword());
    this.setLogin(user.getLogin());
    this.setAuthorities(user.getRoles());
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return getRoles();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return getLogin();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

This is the class MyUser:

```
public class MyUser {

    String login;
    String password;
    List<GrantedAuthority> roles;

    public MyUser(MyUser user) {
        super();
        this.login = user.getLogin();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public List<GrantedAuthority> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

}
```

Any ideas and advice on this topic will be very appreciated.

Comment: You omitted the most important piece, the declaration of `setAuthorities()`.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: There are inconsistencies in your post that make it hard to figure out what's what:   _"This is the MyUserDetails class"_ but the constructor is `UserRepositoryUserDetails`.  Also, what is `UserDB`?  It's pretty clear the list is not being set the way you think, but we can't see the code.

Comment: sorry. it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

In `MyUser` class replace

```
public void setAuthorities(List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
```

with

```
public void setAuthorities(List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    this.roles = authorities;
}
```

Comment: @AbcXyz Things happen. Setter for roles property doesn't follow naming convention and that could made you make the mistake. It'd better to rename it.